# Is a Senate trial required after the House impeaches a president?

Tags: impeachment

If the House of Representatives impeaches a president, everything I read says that there is then a trial by the Senate regarding removal from office. If the House impeaches a president, is it legally necessary to go forward with a Senate trial or is it an option for the House?

Comment: this question was truncated.  My question was, if the house impeaches a president, is it legally necessary to go forward with a senate trial or is it an option for the house?

Comment: @LoanardMFertig: if your question was truncated, you can edit it using the "edit" button found at the bottom of the question, which is recommended, as comments (what this and the above are) are not permanent. Welcome to stack exchange, and I recommend that you take the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), as we are a little different from other sites. Thank you for a wonderful first question, and hopefully you find your time here helpful and productive.

Comment: "is it legally necessary to go forward with a Senate trial or is it an option for the House?" Is actually two different questions: "does the Senate have to go to trial [at all]", and "can either the Senate or the House decide to go to trial (if the other decides not to, for example)".

Comment: What do you mean by "option for the House"? Are you asking if they get to decide whether to send the impeachment to the Senate for a trial? Even if it were, why would they impeach if they didn't want to do this? The vote to impeach is essentially the decision to send to the Senate.

Answer (score 20):

Article I, Section 3, Clause 6 says

> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all 
>    Impeachments. When the President of the United States is tried, the
>    Chief Justice shall preside: And no Person shall be convicted without
>    the Concurrence of two-thirds of the Members present.

Therefore, the House cannot try an impeachment.

The wording of the Constitution does not say "The Senate must try any impeachment delivered by the House". The option to reject an impeachment by simple majority runs completely counter to Senate tradition. But analogous to deployment of the "nuclear option" to change Senate rules, it is a conceivable outcome. The first impeachment presented to the Senate was against a [Senator, William Blount](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/expulsion_cases/Blount_expulsion.htm) in 1797, and in that instance the Senate appears to have voted that Blount was not an impeachable officer (so they did not vote on impeachment, but they did vote to expel him). In [Nixon v. US](https://casetext.com/case/nixon-v-united-states-4), SCOTUS ruled that Senate impeachment actions are not justiciable. While current Senate rules require a trial, the rules can be changed by the Senate by a majority vote, and SCOTUS will not review such actions.

The Senate can also adjourn and not take up one or more articles, as happened in [Andrew Johnson's case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Andrew_Johnson).

Comment: "The option to reject an impeachment by simple majority runs completely counter to Senate tradition": I read recently that some judicial impeachments have been dismissed by the senate rather than tried, or at least one was.  I didn't look into it in detail, however, and I don't know how reliable the source was.

Comment: It's true that the first impeachment was rejected by the Senate, but instead they threw the guy out under their own rules. Blount, 1797. It remains judicially unclear whether a Congressman is "a civil officer of the United States", but by Senate rules, Congressmen cannot be impeached.

Comment: @phoog - I know there have been several judicial impeachments which have been rendered moot by the judge in question retiring.  You can't impeach someone from an office they no longer hold.  I don't know if there have been any actual dismissals of a still-relevant impeachment, though.

Comment: @Bobson interesting point.  The reason for a dismissal would indeed be significant.  Indeed, if it were done because the impeached officer had left the office for one reason or another then that would be quite different from dismissal on grounds related to the merits of the articles of impeachment or for political considerations.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct to say that the trial takes place in the Senate and that the constitution does not say that the Senate must take the issue up. It simply says the Senate shall try all impeachments.

> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments. When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside: And no Person shall be convicted without the Concurrence of two-thirds of the Members present.

Senate rules indicate that the Senate should take up the matter.

> III.  Upon  such  articles  being  presented  to  the  Senate, the Senate shall, at 1 o’clock afternoon of the day (Sunday excepted)  following  such  presentation,  or  sooner  if  ordered by the Senate, proceed to the consideration of such articles and  shall  continue  in  session  from  day  to  day  (Sundays excepted)  after  the  trial  shall  commence  (unless  otherwise ordered  by  the  Senate)  until  final  judgment  shall  be  rendered,  and  so  much  longer  as  may,  in  its  judgment,  be needful.

https://www.law.cornell.edu/background/impeach/senaterules.pdf

Sometimes Senate rules are ignored, but the intent of the rules is clearly that a trial should be held. There may not be an official trial, but under the rules, the decisions of the house must at least be considered by the Senate.

https://www.lawfareblog.com/can-senate-decline-try-impeachment-case

Comment: I agree with all the points you make, but I would add that if the Senate failed to conduct a trial, that its failure to do so would probably be a non-justiciable political question that the courts would not consider or resolve.

Comment: Saying that "the senate shall have the sole power to try" impeachments, which is what the constitution actually says, is very different from saying that the senate " shall try" them as this answer asserts.

Comment: @phoog Did you read the answer? It says the Senate rules indicate the Senate SHOULD take the matter up. No where did I say the constitution says it has to lol.

Comment: @ohwilleke, I would probably agree unless there was some kind of bribery or something like that.

Comment: @Putvi yes, I read the answer.  My comment is in reaction to the sentence "It simply says the Senate shall try all impeachments."  The constitution does not in fact say "the Senate shall try all impeachments"; if it *did* say that then there would be a much stronger case for the position that the constitution requires a trial.

Comment: @phoog you are insinuating I said the constitution requires a trial there. That is why I said read the answer please.

Comment: I'm not insinuating anything.  The sentence in question ("It simply says the Senate shall try all impeachments") uses words that are commonly used in legal writing to create an obligation to do something. That the rest of the answer clarifies the actual requirements of the constitution accurately does not change the meaning of that sentence.  In fact, the sentence just makes the answer confusing because it is inconsistent with the preceding sentence.

Comment: If you say so, I guess lol.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Answering the question made in the comments.

A trial by the Senate is constitutionally required; the House initiates the process of removal, and the Senate then conducts a trial and votes as to whether to remove the President (or a federal judge for that matter) from office.

This is by design; The House is weighted by population, while the Senate has equal representation by State. Both Houses of Congress are required to act in concert for Congress to exercise its unappealable impeachment power against the other branches of government. (For impeaching within the Legislative Branch, each House has sole jurisdiction over itself; i.e. the House of Representatives governs the House of Representatives, and the Senate governs the Senate).

Comment: If you think a Senate trial is required you might ask Merritt Garland how his required Senate advice and consent preceeding went. There is no impeachment for members of Congress but they can be expelled.

Comment: The House impeaches, the Senate convicts.

Comment: @George That is a different situation altogether and need not have the same requirements as a senate impeachment trial. That being said, of the 37 unsuccessful supreme court nominees, only 11 received a vote in the senate. Garland is far from the first to not get a vote.

Comment: This first to essentially not even be acknowledged as having been dully nominated.

Comment: @Matt how were the other 26 nominations resolved? Nominations were withdrawn, candidates withdrew themselves, and perhaps a committee declined to send the nomination to the full senate for consideration.  All of those are quite different from what happened to Merrick Garland, whose nomination was never even considered.

Comment: @phoog Exactly right. One glaring example in recent memory is Harriet Miers. There’s simply no comparing the situations/reasons that caused both her and Garland to not receive committee votes.

Comment: @phoog 11 were withdrawn and 15 lapsed at the end of a session of Congress.

Answer (score -1):

The term "Impeach" when used in this manner is akin to a "charge" by a prosecution of a crime (here the charges are called "Articles of Impeachment") and the Impeached officer is as guilty as someone who is charged with a crime (that is to say, they are presumed innocent until the prosecution proves otherwise).

The House must submit all "Articles of Impeachment" to the Senate and a group of House members will act as Prosecutor while the officer's legal response will be the officer's defense.   Per Senate.gov, the Senate is "The High Court of Impeachment" (and confirmed by SCOTUS in Nixon v. United States) so there is no appeal process for any decision rendered by the Senate.   With exception to the Jury, the trial is like any U.S. trial court (the Jury is the present Senate and conviction is on 2/3rds majority.  If all 100 senators are present, it is 67 yea votes.).  Conviction immediately removes the officer from office and the Senate may at a later date bar the convicted individual from holding future federal office by 51% majority.

While the House must bring charges to the Senate, the Senate has the right to dismiss the charges or adjourn the trial without a vote on a charge, *sine die,* though both cases happened only once for each instance in U.S. History.  As the High Court of Impeachment, these would have the legal effect of dismissal with prejudice in an ordinary judicial court (i.e. the Court refuses to hear this case and will not accept refiling for any reason) and can happen with a 51% majority as well.

Comment: "the Impeached officer is as guilty as someone who is charged with a crime (that is to say, they are presumed guilty until the prosecution proves otherwise)": that's nonsense.  If you are trying to make a rhetorical point, it's lost on me, so the answer just sounds like it was written by someone who doesn't know anything about criminal law.  Or did you simply write "guilty" when you meant to write "innocent"?

Comment: Also, it's not a "51%" majority but a simple majority, which is any percentage greater than 50%, including 50.5%.

Comment: @Sorry, typo.  Will change.  Answer assumes that all 100 sentators are present for the vote, and thus, it's impossible to have a simple majority vote that is greater than 50% but less than 51% of the vote, since we do not sub divide Senator votes.

Comment: But all senators don't need to be present, of course.  If only 51 are present, the minimum majority is 26/51, which is 50.98%.  I know it seems nitpicky, but I have seen a lot of misunderstandings about this, including some bylaws that said that a motion must pass with at least "50% plus 1" votes, which led to an argument about whether, with seven votes cast, the minimum vote would have to be 5 against 2 (because `50% * 7 + 1` is 4.5, and 5 is the smallest whole number greater than 4.5) or 4 against 3 (because the bylaws were obviously just using an incorrect definition of simple majority).